# Is there a microtime.h library for C

Tags: c, microtime

I have a C program that has `#include <microtime.h>` in the header, but when I compile it with GCC or g++, it shows the error -

```
fatal error: microtime.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <microtime.h>
```

How could I compile it. I am not sure if I need to download this microtime separately?

Comment: That is no standard C header. If your program uses some library that comes with a `microtime.h` header file, you need to check dependencies of that program which library was used. There should be some installation instructions etc.. Basically any library could call their header `microtime.h` and you need to get the correct one.

Comment: The build instruction should also give a hint what library was used as the lib itself would need to be linked together with the other files.

Answer (score 0):

use quotes:-

```
#include "microtime.h"
```

Using quotes will look in the same directory first, and then in the specified include paths. Using angle brackets `<>` will look in the include paths only.